# Finding the desired links via Regex

Tags: python, regex, jenkins

I am a beginner in Regex but I am trying to implement it.
What I am trying to do is I want to extract the links that are present in specific files via regex and print them out.
Below are the links all in one place that I want to extarct:

```
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/openjdk8_hs_openjdktest_s390x_linux/18/consoleFull

https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/Test_openjdk11_hs_sanity.openjdk_x86-64_mac/26/consoleFull

To reproduce: https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk14_hs_sanity.openjdk_ppc64_aix/111/console

Jenkins Build URL: https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk8_hs_extended.system_ppc64le_linux/259/

internal build `Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/`

internal build `Test_openjdk11_j9_sanity.functional_aarch64_linux/46`
```

I want the links in the form of (Expected):

```
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/openjdk8_hs_openjdktest_s390x_linux/18/
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/Test_openjdk11_hs_sanity.openjdk_x86-64_mac/26/
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk14_hs_sanity.openjdk_ppc64_aix/111/
Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/
```

To solve it I tried to apply regex concept and came up with this pattern:
`` (?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/ci.adoptopenjdk.net.+(?:consoleFull|console|\d?))|(?:\`.+?\`) ``

But the output comes like this (Actual):

```
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk17_j9_sanity.openjdk_x86-64_linux/33/consoleFull

https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/openjdk8_hs_openjdktest_s390x_linux/18/consoleFullhttps://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk11_hs_sanity.openjdk_ppc64_aix/145/`Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/`
`cent7-aarch64-3``Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/`
`cent7-aarch64-3`
```

Now I wanted to check on the basis of https://....Test_openjdk{num} as `ci.adoptopenjdk.net` is outdated
To encounter this situation I made a regex pattern to check all the links as mentioned above as inputs on the basis of Test_openjdk{num} to get the desired output.
I used

```
(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/Test_openjdk/\d.+\/(?=console)|(?<=\`).+?\/(?=\`)
```

but only got the following output:

```
Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/
Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/
```

I have been trying various ways but they all are failing.
Can anyone explain me where and why am I going wrong it would really be great.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/ci\.adoptopenjdk\.net.+\/|(?:\`.+?\`))
```

`.+\/` will make sure you stop the match at the last / in your link

also `.` means match any character if you wanna match "." exactly use `\.`

If you only want the ones that end in console or /' and your regex flavor supports positive lookahead and positive lookbehind you can use this

```
(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/ci\.adoptopenjdk\.net.+\/(?=console)|(?<=\`).+?\/(?=\`)
```

`(?=console)` means it has to be followed by string console but it will not capture it

`` (?<=\`) `` means that there has to be a backtick before the match but it will not capture it

`` (?=\`) `` means that there has to a backtick after the match but it will not capture it

regarding your python function problem you need to join with \n and print the result of the function

```
import re
def regexify(s):
    pattern = r"(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/ci\.adoptopenjdk\.net.+\/(?=console)|(?<=\`).+?\/(?=\`)"
    substring = re.findall(pattern, s)
    result='\n'.join(substring)
    if result:
        try:
            return result
        except:
            return ' '
x='''
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/openjdk8_hs_openjdktest_s390x_linux/18/consoleFull

https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/Test_openjdk11_hs_sanity.openjdk_x86-64_mac/26/consoleFull

To reproduce: https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk14_hs_sanity.openjdk_ppc64_aix/111/console

Jenkins Build URL: https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk8_hs_extended.system_ppc64le_linux/259/

internal build `Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/`

internal build `Test_openjdk11_j9_sanity.functional_aarch64_linux/46` 
'''
print(regexify(x))
```

Output:

```
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/openjdk8_hs_openjdktest_s390x_linux/18/
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/Test_openjdk/job/Test_openjdk11_hs_sanity.openjdk_x86-64_mac/26/
https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/job/Test_openjdk14_hs_sanity.openjdk_ppc64_aix/111/
Test_openjdk8_j9_sanity.openjdk_aarch64_linux/43/
```

Comment: Hello @nechesstich thank you for your help but it just showing a glitch, the backticks aren't getting ignored and everything is in the same line. Can you look
Thank you

Comment: @Asjadkhan i updated the answer to remove backticks. if you want newlines in your python code you have to join the strings with \n and you have to print the output of the function

Comment: Thank you so much @nechesstich it works. Would be forever grateful  to you for this.

Comment: Hello @nechesstich for the backticks parts if there are multiple contents within backticks and I just want the first pair, how will I change it? Is there a way.

Comment: @Asjadkhan yes there is a way re.findall returns you a list so you can just take the first match by doing re.findall(pattern, s)[0] since you want different behavior for with and without backticks i would sugest spliting the pattern into two and then only taking the first match of your backtick pattern

Comment: Yeah I've followed the same approach:
```
pattern = r"((?:http|ftp|https):\/\/.+\/job\/Test_openjdk\d+.+\/\d+)" 
    substring = re.findall(pattern, s)
    result='\n'.join(substring)
    pattern2 = r"(?<=\`).+?\/(?=\`)"
    substring2 = re.findall(pattern2, s)[0]
    result2='\n'.join(substring2)
    final_link = ''.join(('https://internal_jenkins/job/',result2))
    if result:
        try:
            return result
        except:
            return ' '
    elif result2:
        try:
            return final_link
        except:
            return ' '
```

Comment: But @nechesstich I get the error:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Asjadkhan you are getting that error because that patter didn't match so it returned an empty list. So you first have to check if the list is empty and then if it isn't take the first index.
Something like
substring2 = re.findall(pattern2, s)
if substring2 != []:
    substring2=substring2[0]
else:
    substring2=""